# Install python enviroment python=3.5.2

Tags: python, anaconda

> **EDIT 2021: DONT USE PYTHON 3.5.2 ( version is no longer supported )**

I tried to create a conda python environment with python=3.5.2 and get bellows errors.

1. How can i add a custom link for installation ?
   e.g. https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/3.5.2/download/win-64/python-3.5.2-0.tar.bz2

`conda create -n eapp_env python=3.5.2`

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: failed with current_repodata.json, will retry with next
> repodata source. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels:
>
> - python=3.5.2
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
> you're looking for, navigate to
>
> ```
> https://anaconda.org
> ```
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: @James `conda create -n eapp_env python=3.5.2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like only 3.5.4, 3.5.5, and 3.5.6 are available on the main/win-64 index of the  anaconda channel.  I am not sure why they removed previous versions of 3.5.

You can switch channels to conda-forge, which still has all of the versions available.

```
conda create -n eapp_env python=3.5.2 --channel conda-forge
```

Just as an FYI typically the sub-sub-version of a package only has minor updates and will not affect anything else in your environment.