# cannot import python 3.5.9

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

hi I try to install `python=3.5.9` in my virtual environment

so first I try this: `conda create -n envname python=3.5.9 anaconda`

and I did not work as the package was not in the channel

then I search StackOverflow channel and I find this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768688/install-python-enviroment-python-3-5-2](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768688/install-python-enviroment-python-3-5-2)

so I try `conda install python=3.5.9 --channel conda-forge` and did not work

then I go to [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org) and I searched for python `3.5.9` and I was not able to find something only but the version `3.5`

so I try again the above `conda install python=3.5 --channel conda-forge` and now in my environment, I have `3.5.5.` But what I want is to have python `3.5.9`.

any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to install python 3.5.9 in your pc using its installer?

Comment: how to do this specific my virtual environment?

Comment: If you do `conda search python`, you'll see which versions of Python are supported. I don't see 3.5.9 listed there, so I think it's simply not supported by conda.